# Swift to android equivalent

Tags: android, swift

I am looking for an  easier way to do this in Android

Swift code:

```
if let person = company.group?.person where !person .isEmpty {
    return true 
}
return false
```

Equivalent Android Code:

```
String person = ""
if (Company != null) {
    if(company.group != null) {
        if(company.group.person != null) {
            if (!person.isEmpty){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

return false;
```

Is there an easier way to do this in Android without getting null exception. `group` and `person` can be null value too.

Comment: `return !company.group?.person.isEmpty ?? false` Just a shorter version in Swift :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If person is a `String`:

```
return company != null
    && company.group != null
    && !TextUtils.isEmpty(company.group.person);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a `Company` instance named `company` and the existence of the usual getter methods, especially `getPerson()` with return type `String`:

```
if (company == null || company.getGroup() == null 
    || company.getGroup().getPerson() == null 
    || company.getGroup().getPerson().length() == 0 )
{
    return false;
}

return true;
```